# How to change route with react-router-dom <Link> without calling url and not request to server

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use `react-route-dom` in React SSR (server side rendering) project. when i click on Links i want change route but not request to server (not request  in SPA mode - request only in direct call)

i think we can use `event.preventDefault()` to stop default action of  but i don't know how do it with Link.

Comment: Did you code for your route?

Comment: @tareqaziz  clone it (https://github.com/ebrahimiaval/RSSR) and log req.url in server.js